# I hid a body in a container, but I really need the body's clothes — How do I get the clothes?

Tags: hitman-absolution

So, I hid a body in a container. But then I realized that I needed this guy's clothes. How do I get the clothes of a body I already put in a container?

The container where I hid the body is full (contains two bodies) already. I don't know if I could open this container and still get this guy's clothes.

EDIT:
Turns out that I couldn't steal this guy's clothes at all. That's why I didn't get the option to take his clothes. Anyway, does anyone know if I will still be given the option to take the body's clothes if only one of the bodies (the first one put) in the container can have his clothes taken, and the other can't?
[image]

Comment: It seem's that you can't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you approach the container you will be given the usual option of taking the dead guy's clothes. You may need to try different angles, but it is most certainly possible.

Comment: Turns out that I couldn't steal the guy's clothes at all (see my question edit). Anyway, do you know if I will still be given the option to take the body's clothes if only one of the bodies (the first one put) in the container can have his clothes taken, and the other can't?